# how do I use mootools

Tags: mootools

Help me with installing this please

Answer (score 1):

This is so easy, you should just google it and you will find plenty of answers. But here is the answer anyway.

First of all you should check out [mootools.net](http://mootools.net) which has a lot of demos, too. Just download the **.js** file there and include the script-path in your **header**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mootools is very well documented but my advice is go over http://www.mootorial.com/ there to will find very simple tutorials and books. This should be plenty to get you started. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript libraries do not require installation like other libraries.  You just download, unzip if the download is zipped, and include the JavaScript files in the <head> tag.  With Mootools, it's even easier because you can leverage the Google-hosted Mootools files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.2.4/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.2.4/mootools.js"></script>
```

*If you need to know the difference between the two, that should probably be another question by itself.*

Here's the reference for Mootools hosted on Google:
http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#mootools